# Rowspan when <a> element is clicked with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, coding-style, html-table

I was trying to get this with divs and css, but I was advice to do it with JQuery and tables instead.

The case is that I am trying to make a two rows table with 5 cells in first row and 4 on second.

When you click on one of the `<a>` inside of the cells on the top, that cell will span the row and change background-image, taking the correspondent space between the cells below.

Default state.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td><a href="#" rowspan="2"/>1</td>
   <td><a href="#"/>2</td>
   <td><a href="#"/>3</td>
   <td><a href="#"/>4</td>
   <td><a href="#"/>5</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="#"/>6</td>
   <td><a href="#"/>7</td>
   <td><a href="#"/>8</td>
   <td><a href="#"/>9</td>
</tr>
```

how should it look by default

```
______________________________________
|      |_______|_______|______|______|
|______|_______|_______|______|______|
```

how should it look if any of second row is selected.

```
______________________________________
|______|_______|________|______|______|
   |_______|_______|________|_______|
```

What I am trying to do its a two row tab menu so when the user select any tab from the first row the image of the tab will e get longer, taking the space of the missing cell bellow.

Sorry to all, of course if it is a lot of work do not bother, I don't know how much work this would involve as I don't know anything about JQuery, thanks anyway for looking.

I am in a rush to get this done and if I stop to learn JQuery now I may get told off, that is why I am looking for a quick solution ( I know it sounds terrible, but I can spend the time right now)

Comment: In the default view, is the top-first tab selected? If so, it makes sense to me, but I dont understand the second view.

Comment: Sorry, it would be if any of the second row is selected, therefore it would make it more consistent, and no item from first row would be  with rowspan which it may be confusing for the user to define which its been selected.

Comment: What you describe cannot be done in a table, because a table is by definition a grid. your second example does not adhere to a grid definition since the cells do not align with the first row of the same table..

Comment: Like gaby said, the second example is not possible with only one table.  You would need to make a second table in the second row and center align it with a shorter width and that sounds terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you ask. But I don't know how this would do anything for you :) so maybe I've misunderstood you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SO</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('table tr:first td a').click(function(){
                $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td[rowspan]').attr('rowspan', 1);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">3</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">4</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">5</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">6</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">7</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">8</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">9</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```